# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in C:\wamp\www\b_php\project\login_save.php on line 14

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I got the error in this code. What's wrong in this code?
With parse error it also gave this error ( SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for).

```
1.     <?php   
2.    session_start(); 
3.      $name=$_POST['email']; //email, pass is the id='' field from table
4.      $passs=$_POST['pass'];
5.        mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //db connection file
6.      mysql_select_db("secg");
7.       $_SESSION['email']='$name'; //for security purpose
8.   $result=mysql_query("select * from student where Email='$name and password='$passs'");
9.          $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
10.        if($row>0)
11.           {
12.              header("location:index.htm");  }
13.           else  {
14.           die('could not be opened because of' mysql_error() ); }               
15.    ?>
```

Comment: Apart from the major security issues...?

Comment: Please go learn PHP syntax basics.

Comment: What about reading the error message?

Comment: What would happen if I entered : `test'"); DROP TABLE student;--` as the pass? - http://bobby-tables.com/ Also `mysql_` is deprecated, instead use `mysqli_`

Comment: `"select * from student where Email='$name and password='$passs'"` has multiple issues... Both security-wise and syntax. You should hire a programmer...

Answer (score 5):

There is a missing dot in that die()

```
die('could not be opened because of'.mysql_error())
```

Comment: your string concatenation is incorrect, would have been a better wording for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $name;
```

And after tha sql query give this

```
die('could not be opened because of'.mysql_error())
```

Because It will gives you the mysql error and also dont use `mysql_*` statements because they are **deprecated**.Insted use `mysqli_*` statements or `PDO statements`

Answer (score 1):

There is a dot missing:

```
die('could not be opened because of' . mysql_error() );
```